# Alternative to OR statement

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is redirect countries, based on country code with the script below. The code below does not work. Doing some research I found I have to use an or statement or at least that's what I think I need, but my question is there an easier way then an or statement? As you can see there are a lot countries I am checking for.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

var country= geoip_country_code();

if(country = "UK","CA","DE","DK","FR","AU","SE","CH","NL","IT","BE","AT","ES","NO","IE","FI","GB","US")      
{
window.location.href='http://www.google.com'; 
}
else   
{
window.location.href='http://www.yahoo.com'; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It's trivial to bypass server-side as well.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but this will be good enough for what I need.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The point is that security cannot matter here anyway.  No region-locking by IP address is effective beyond the average user.  Besides, he's just redirecting.

Comment: @Brad Point taken. I'd still do-it server-side though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
var countryCodes = ["UK","CA","DE","DK","FR","AU","SE","CH","NL","IT","BE","AT","ES","NO","IE","FI","GB","US"];
var country= geoip_country_code();
if (countryCodes.indexOf(country) !== -1)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @BenS.—whether `!=` or `!==` is used is irrelevant, I'd suggest that `!=` is preferred as there is no reason to use `!==`.

Comment: @RobG I know - I just meant that it is generally a good habit to use `!==` unless you have a specific reason not to, since in most cases it is probably what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var country = 'US';
var countries = 'UK CA DE DK FR AU SE CH NL IT BE AT ES NO IE FI GB US';

if (countries.match(country.toUpperCase())) {
  // matched
} else {
  // no match
}
```

But it's very easy for the client to spoof its origin.